# Removing category/article numbers in SEF

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, sef, apache

The instructions and links in [this answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/697/79) clearly demonstrated how to make search engine friendly URLs.  However the URLs I currently see on my website have the format:

> mydomain.com/1-category/2-title

and I would like the URLS to be

> mydomain.com/category/title

Is this possible/safe to do?  I am using shared hosting and apache.

Comment: A [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs) to the documentation FAQ about SEFs (so I remember where it is...)

Comment: [And a link to a similar question that tries to deal with the same thing programmatically](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/988/remove-article-id-from-joomla-3-url?lq=1)

Comment: @FFrewin Do you think mine Q should be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: :: not sure - as mentioned in my comment the other question is a coding approach by modifying the com_content's router. Your question is about the same thing but from a kind different perspective. Interesting to what other members have to say. The funny is that I now see the 2 questions posted with 1 day difference.

Comment: This issue will likely be fixed in Joomla 3.7.0 which has a new router and is due to be released soon.

Answer (score 6):

With the core routing system, there isn't a practical way to accomplish it.  You can use a tool like [sh404SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134) to achieve this though.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a menu item for each of these then the menu item alias is used for the URL instead.

The menu you create these links in doesn't have to be published on your site, it's enough that the menu item exists in menu manager. You can create a new menu called 'dummy links', or whatever you like, and create links to your categories and articles there. You don't need to show that menu anywhere on your site.

Comment: This solution would quickly become cumbersome for a larger site.  It's an interesting solution for what I've got at the moment, though.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is one of the most common questions around Joomla, I though to share a new extension I came across that deals with it.

### Plugin: Direct Alias Pro

For those people that don't want to mess with the extended capabilities of the majority of SEF extensions, this a much simpler plugin, that one of each features is to remove ids from articles, categories and tags SEF Urls.

**Developer**: Alterbrains
**Type**: Paid Download

Answer (score 1):

Other extensions that might be worth a look are those in the [URL-Canonicalization](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/url-canonicalization-) category, for example, Canonical.