# Remove Article ID from Joomla 3 url

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, url

I am trying to remove the article id from a Joomla 3 URL. I searched around and the response is in

```
components\com_content\router.php
```

change `0` to `1` in `$advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 1);`

on lines *38* and *290*

and also commented out

```
if (strpos($segments[0], ':') === false) {
    $vars['view'] = 'article';
    $vars['id'] = (int)$segments[0];
    return $vars;
}
```

I consider it works fine in Joomla 2.5 as all comments mention this.

But it does not do the job for me on my Joomla 3.3 website.

How can I achieve this without creating menu items for each article?

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: Simply create a menu link for your article.

Comment: Lodder - Yes, I get the link I want, but have 404 error page instead of my article.

Comment: Saibbyweb - I have more than a 100 articles and the number is to grow up to 500, so I don't think it is a good idea to create menu for all these.

Comment: If the extension K2 an option for you, then you can achieve this really easy. K2 has options for advanced routing, with the needed options. You can import you excisting articles into K2. Check my K2 Blog and the generated readmore links. Another solution is to use something like sh404sef or youwait for this https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/advance-the-joomla-url-router/x/7216161

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Step 1**

Edit “components/com_content/router.php“, then continue on step 2.
**(You’ll probably have to re-do this step every time you update Joomla.)**

**Step 2**

(There are two places need to do this change, one near the top, one in the middle)
Replace this:

`$advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 0);`

With this:

`$advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 1);`

**Step 3**

Replace

`->where($db->quoteName(‘alias’) . ‘ = ‘ . $db->quote($db->quote($segment)));`

with

`->where($db->quoteName(‘alias’) . ‘ = ‘ . $db->quote($segment));`

and you're done.

Comment: you're welcome @gag

Comment: I have tried the above solution on my 3.3.3 site to no avail. The complete site would go blank.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that don't want to get dirty with editing Joomla code, we shall mention that 3rd party SEF extensions provide the ability to remove the ids from the SEF urls.

There are plenty of SEF extensions someone can find in [**JED**](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/site-management/sef):

For example [**SH404SEF**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/sef/sh404sef), is one of the most popular and used Joomla extensions, with long history and extended support by many 3rd party components.

As for a simpler solution, I recently came across a new plugin that provides a few features including "Remove ids from article, categories and tags SEF urls". Simple and easy solution that works.

*Note1: Both the extensions mentioned above are paid downloads.

*Note2: there is another a similar question in [JSE](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/984/removing-category-article-numbers-in-sef/10204#10204).

Comment: Piggybacking on this, I am a fan of Direct Alias which is a plugin that just removes the article/category IDs and nothing else.  Nice solution if you don't want a whole SEF component.  https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/sef/direct-alias/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing answers, a new router is included in Joomla 3.7.0 which will likely fix this problem.

Joomla 3.7.0 is due to be released soon. For details, see:

https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5695-joomla-3-7-0-alpha-2-released.html

Comment: Has this problem actually been fixed? I still have it with 3.10. Maybe I'm not seeing the option? (sorry about posting in this old thread, but it was the first that came up on Google)

Comment: There are some circumstances where IDs are still shown. The easiest way to fix this is a third party extension such as the free or paid version of Alter Brains Direct Alias which is available for Joomla 3 and Joomla 4.