# SEF URL using router without id in the URL

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef, jroute

Non SEF URL

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=article&id=20&Itemid=50
```

SEF URL

```
http://www.example.com/example-menu-item/20
```

Is it possible to create SEF without the value 20 in the URL.  We believe having 20 in the URL exposes the primary key of the record.

Comment: One way is to do create menu item for each of the article. That will allow you full control on the URL. But I think you are talking about something similar to this:

http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/988/remove-article-id-from-joomla-3-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess URL Rewrite replacing the numeric segment to something else but you have to make sure your item's alias column is unique in your component's table unless the same URL segments being generated will conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joomla Rewriting and .htaccess file:

System >> Global Configuration >> Use URL Rewriting YES;
Rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess in your root folder;
Implement in your .htaccess file one rule like this:

```
## Mod_rewrite
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[0-9]/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can see complete explanation how rewrite works here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html