# How i can change the URL (index.php)

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x

How do I get rid of the /index.php/ parent of my webpages? When you click through my pages, they are always /index.php/about-us, I just want it to be /about-us.

Comment: This question has already been asked and asnwered: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/696/how-to-remove-the-index-from-urls

Answer (score 2):

Your are running in the default SEF mode. To change it you have to enable any of the alternatives. Check Joomla documentation, here:

**Enabling Search Engine Friendly (SEF) URLs**
https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs