# remove index.php from breadcrumbs home link

Tags: joomla-3.x

My joomla version is 3.7.5. The home link in breadcrumbs is "domain/index.php". I want to remove the index.php part.
How i can modify the code from breadcrumbs helper file to achive this?

```
$item->link = JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=' . $home->id);
        array_unshift($crumbs, $item);
```

If i replace index.php with / the result is "domain/101 (menu id)".

Comment: Have a look at this question. The answers will most likely help you: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/696/168

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i don't want to remove index.php global. I want to remove it, only in breadcrumbs link for home page.

Comment: Ah I see. Perhaps just replace it using `str_replace` then? http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Do as @Lodder recommend - the use of .htaccess has so many advantages - both SEF, SEO and security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `'index.php?Itemid=' . $home->id` with my domain and problem fixed. Unfortunately, (correct comment from FFrewin below) like all core hacks, with every joomla update, i must change the file again (can't use template override for helper.php files).
Then i found mvc override plugin from [joomla documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core) and i made template override for mod_breadcrumbs/helper.php file. It works fine.

Comment: Note that if you have modified a core file, you will have to maintain this change when you update Joomla!, as most likely it will be overwritten by the updates.

Comment: @FFrewin correct. I edited my answer. Thank you.